# Why can't Mathematica evaluate this limit of 2F1, which actually is a polynomial?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Consider the following function:

```
test = (1 - q) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1 + q)/2, 2, 1 - q, x];
```

It's quite obvious from the definition of $_2F_1$ that the above function is a polynomial in `x`. This can be easily confirmed as follows (although this is not a proof):

```
stest = Series[test, {x, 0, 40}];
Limit[stest, q -> 1]
```

> -2 x

But `Limit[test, q -> 1]` leaves the limit unevaluated. Why can't *Mathematica* calculate this limit? It seems straightforward to do from the definition of the hypergeometric series.

Comment: `Hypergeometric2F1` is `1` for all other values when `a` is `0`.

Comment: "Why can't Mathematica calculate this limit?" - recall that `Limit[]` uses the machinery of `Series[]` under the hood, and ponder on the result of `Series[(1 - q) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1 + q)/2, 2, 1 - q, x], {q, 1, 2}]`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround for evaluating your limit is to use a contiguity relation for the Gaussian hypergeometric function like [this one](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/02/02/0001/):

```
(1 - q) Hypergeometric2F1[2, (-1 - q)/2, 1 - q, z] ==
(-1 - q)/2 Hypergeometric2F1[2, (1 - q)/2, 2 - q, z] +
(3 - q)/2 Hypergeometric2F1[2, (-1 - q)/2, 2 - q, z] // FullSimplify
   True

(-1 - q)/2 Hypergeometric2F1[2, (1 - q)/2, 2 - q, z] +
(3 - q)/2 Hypergeometric2F1[2, (-1 - q)/2, 2 - q, z] /. q -> 1
   -2 z
```